# HTML- Content not rendered properly in IE else it works just perfect in FF / chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following thing on the image is perfect in FF / chrome. Like the required behavior is achieved but when on IE its completely messed up.
I had been in loop past few hours. Please help. Thanks.

![this is messed up in IE
http://kishanthobhani.goodluckwith.us/mess.PNG

here is my code:
http://kishanthobhani.goodluckwith.us/myseagatecode.txt

---

Just to let you know, we added Doctype to the My Pages, and it fixed the alignment issues that were only seen in IE8. Thanks everyone.

Comment: show us your code, read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: How are we supposed to offer help based on an image?

Comment: Can anyone connect to my teamviewer because the content on the page is rendered dynamically from a vignette portal using JSP. and for me to access it i have log in into clients VPN.

Comment: You can always make a simplified example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: urmmm i am all newbie here so i still have to figure out how stuff works but anyways for now i have posted a link to my code.. will it be any useful?

Comment: Good you have given your code but dear how can we access your css and javascript files, all these are relative to code only and no direct access i mean the css/js files link where it is uploaded. Provide the fiddle instead or upload your files some where so we can see the issues. IE ver?

Comment: @HappySingh: The problem is there's no doctype, so IE is in quirks mode. A valid doctype needs to be added above the HTML comments. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @thirtydot - oh ya it might be the cause because IE always give such kind of problem when DOCTYPE not included in header. Anyways i am not sure about this in this situation so i cant write the answer on basis of DOCTYPE.

Comment: @HappySingh  thank you sir for your feedback and urmm no thats quite not possible to put it on fiddle as whatever pages we get are generated by JSP/Vignette portal. n i was working with IE 9

Comment: @thirtydot i will try that but i dont think so that wouldbe problem because all other pages we have are rendered perfectly. and they have same head & foot. Can a small error cause a problem? Like if a DIV is not closed. ? likely it should not mess whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no Doctype, this means your page will be rendered in Quirks mode in which browsers attempt to emulate buggy software from the 90s instead of following the standard.

Start your HTML with [a Doctype that triggers Standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

You also have a number of errors that some basic automated QA (from a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)) would pick up. You should correct those too.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your html using http://validator.w3.org/. When your html passes, post a pic of what it should look like (the current pic being the problem).